# Remove the item from array in javascript titanium

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, titanium, removechild

This is my json array:

```
var myObjectString = JSON.stringify(data);
Ti.API.info("PRICE" + " " + myObjectString);

[{
    "name": "Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan",
    "image": "/images/T/xctmpQmkaHM.png",
    "totalPrice": 999,
    "itemPrice": 999,
    "itemCount": 1
}]
```

Here i need to remove the image element(key+value) and store the value like below :

```
[{
    "name": "Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan",
    "totalPrice": 999,
    "itemPrice": 999,
    "itemCount": 1
}]
```

How can i do ? i need to save this result in another var ? how can i do ? how can i get the above result.

**EDIT:**

From **Alex Alksne** comment :

the statically assigned code is working fine.

But if we are assigning a value as dynamically means it's not working.

```
var myObjectString = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(myObjectString);
delete myObjectString[0].image;
 console.log(myObjectString);
```

[{"name":"Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan","image":"/images/T/xctmpQmkaHM.png","totalPrice":999,"itemPrice":999,"itemCount":1}]

[{"name":"Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan","image":"/images/T/xctmpQmkaHM.png","totalPrice":999,"itemPrice":999,"itemCount":1}]

Comment: I see what you mean now; make sure not to run `var myObjectString = JSON.stringify(data);` before you use `delete`. `delete` only works on Objects and not Strings. So just `delete` first, and then `stringify()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove both the key and value in a Javascript object, you need to use the `delete` keyword (simply assigning `PRICE[0].image = undefined` will only remove the value).

So for example, if your data structure looked like:

```
var myObject;
myObject = 
[{ 
  "name": "Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan", 
  "image": "/images/T/xctmpQmkaHM.png", 
  "totalPrice": 999, 
  "itemPrice": 999, 
  "itemCount": 1 
}]
```

You would remove the image key/value pair by writing: `delete myObject[0].image`. Now, if you `console.log(myObject)`, you would get:

```
[{ 
  "name": "Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan", 
  "totalPrice": 999, 
  "itemPrice": 999, 
  "itemCount": 1 
}]
```

Something to keep in mind is the `delete` keyword only works on Objects and not Strings. If your data was originally in the form of a String, you have to `JSON.parse(myObject)` before you can use `delete` on it. For example:

```
var myObjectString = 
'[{
  "name": "Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan", 
  "image": "/images/T/xctmpQmkaHM.png", 
  "totalPrice": "999", 
  "itemPrice": "999", 
  "itemCount": "1"
}]'

var myObject = JSON.parse(myObjectString);
delete myObject[0].image;
```

Comment: PRICE value is not there...how can i identified the PRICE value from here....i ahve declared the var myObjectString; myObjectString = [{
    "name": "Bajaj 200 mm Ultima PT01 Personal Fan",
    "image": "/images/T/xctmpQmkaHM.png",
    "totalPrice": 999,
    "itemPrice": 999,
    "itemCount": 1
}]

Comment: Please check my updated question...static means it's working...dynamically assigned the value means it's not working.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working was because you were trying to use `delete` on a String. You need to convert the String to an Object before you can do that. Let me know if this is closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Yes i got the output from your  comments delete only works on Objects and not Strings. So just delete first, and then stringify()..Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

try "delete" as..

```
delete PRICE[0].image;
```